# How to mask image with color in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Basically I want to remove the background color of image from image.
that why I want to mask my image with clear color, it can make the image transparent.

or do we have any other way to clear the backgrund color of image and get transparent image.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new image with by masking  background using CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors. Specify the background color range(RGB) values. That would be enough to create background transparent image.